# How to configure Azure Logic Apps to Execute Azure Data Factory on specific date

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am extremely new to Azure Logic Apps, but I've been told that Azure Data Factory is not capable handling complex scheduling.

Therefore, I have create an Azure Logic App service, I have made a start, but I am completely lost.

I am trying to trigger an Azure Data Factory pipeline based on the following date

```
Last Month End but one e.g. 30/04/2023
```

I thought this would be easy to create a Trigger for this in ADF, but it looks like I need to use Logic Apps.

[image]

Any help most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UX way I would go for:
[image: ux way is easier]

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Condition": {
            "actions": {},
            "else": {
                "actions": {
                    "show_last_month_date": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "demo value",
                            "value": "@{subtractFromTime(startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(),1,'month')),1,'day')}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                }
            },
            "expression": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "equals": [
                            "@variables('LHS')",
                            "@variables('RHS')"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "demo": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "If"
        },
        "day_of_month": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "LHS",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": "@int(dayOfMonth(utcNow()))"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "last_day_of_month": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "demo": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "demo value",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "day_of_month": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "last_day_of_month": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "RHS",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": "@int(formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(),1,'month')),1,'day'),'dd'))"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "Recurrence_daily": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "schedule": {
                    "hours": [
                        "1"
                    ],
                    "minutes": [
                        10
                    ]
                },
                "startTime": "2023-06-06T12:00:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "type": "recurrence"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {} }
```

The code wise wise way to achieve this:

- The [following example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence?tabs=consumption) is available in MS shows how to update the
  trigger definition so that the trigger runs only once on the last day
  of each month:

  ```
   "triggers": {
   "Recurrence": {
       "recurrence": {
           "frequency": "Month",
           "interval": 1,
           "schedule": {
               "monthDays": [-1]
           }
       },
       "type": "Recurrence"
   }
  ```

  }

Take a look at the below as well:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26707